# How to name the file in "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm" in android?

Tags: android

In my app project, I want to take picture from second-front camera and it is saved in StringFormat like "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm". I use this code,but it TOASt me:"Can't Saved."(try-catch part). would you please help me, why my photo doesn't save?

```
public onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    File pictureFileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Dahesh");
    pictureFileDir.mkdir();


    if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {

        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Can't create directory to save image");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't make path to save pic.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;

    }


    Calendar calender =Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss a");
   //String fileName = simpleDateFormat.format(calender.getTime());
    String fileName =pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + simpleDateFormat.format(calender.getTime());
    fileName=fileName.replace(":","_");
    fileName=fileName.replace("","_");
    File pictureFile =new File(fileName);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved as latest_mug.jpg",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception error) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "File not saved: " + error.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't save image.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you even write that code? Anyway, it's probably due to the mounted filesystem not allowing characters like ':' try to change your formatting so it doesn't have any special characters.

Comment: i use this code from this link:"
https://code.google.com/p/android-mt-tutorials/source/browse/tags/Mirror-1/src/com/mamlambo/mirror/MirrorActivity.java
" and i customixe it. thanks alot, because your guidness.

Comment: i change “simpleDateFormat” into "yyyymmdd_hhmmss".

Comment: and also edit this line "String fileName =pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + simpleDateFormat.format(calender.getTime())+" .jpg";